# php foreach loop and if condition gives extra null value

Tags: php, foreach

I have an array from a feed with following print_r output:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (

        [name] => Cell Phone Case

        [options] => Array
            (
                [Colors] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Clear
                        [1] => Red
                        [2] => Blue        
                    )
            )

Array
(
[1] => Array
    (

        [name] => Iphone
            )

Array
(
[2] => Array
    (

        [name] => Tablet

        [options] => Array
            (
                [Color] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => White
                        [1] => Black
                        [2] => Red 
                    )

            )
```

The feed unfortunately is providing colors in two values, for some products it is:

```
options['Colors']
```

and for some other

```
options['Color'].
```

My code to insert the values into DB is as follows:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO product_colors(product_id, colors) VALUES(:pid, :colors)");


if (!is_array($value['options']['Colors'])) {
$value['options']['Colors'] = array($value['options']['Colors']);
}
if (!is_array($value['options']['Color'])) {
$value['options']['Color'] = array($value['options']['Color']);
}


//Colors or Color
$colorArr = array();
if(isset($value['options']['Colors'])) {
 $colorArr = $value['options']['Colors'];
}
if(isset($value['options']['Color'])) {
$colorArr = array_merge($colorArr, $value['options']['Color']);
}

$PID = ($conn->lastInsertId());

foreach ($colorArr as $colors) {
$stmt->execute(array(':pid' => $PID, ':colors' => $colors));
}
```

The data is getting inserted except that a null value is also inserted at the beginning, except for product 1 (at end ) for each product color values.

print_r($colorArr);  gives the following array output:

```
Array
(
[0] => Clear
[1] => Red
[2] => Blue
[3] =>
)
```

An extra null value after the 3 colors for product 1...

Please note that some products do not have color value like the iphone in array 2.

How can i correct this issue ??? I need the product colors inserted into DB for the corresponding product id, even if options are both **Colors** or **Color**.

Help requested....

**Update:**

I have corrected the issue myself. The default php array_merge function doesn't merge values if any subsequent array's field is empty. This function rectifies it as follows:

```
function array_merge_corrected($array_a=array(),$array_b=array()){
$array_merge= array();
if(!empty($array_a)&& !empty($array_b)){
foreach($array_a as $field=>$value){
$array_merge[$field]= $value;
}
foreach($array_b as $field=>$value){
if(!empty($value)){
$array_merge[$field]= $value;
} elseif(!array_key_exists($field,$array_a)){
$array_merge[$field]= $value;
}
}
}
return $array_merge;
}


$colorArr = array_merge_corrected($colorArr, $value['options']['Color']);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the culprit is this bit of the code:

```
if (!is_array($value['options']['Colors'])) {
    $value['options']['Colors'] = array($value['options']['Colors']);
}
if (!is_array($value['options']['Color'])) {
    $value['options']['Color'] = array($value['options']['Color']);
}
```

This creates an array if it's not already an array, including in the case when there is actually nothing. So you get an array containing a null value.

Comment: @user3790186, definitely not the most efficient way of doing it. The good solution is to test if the value is also non-null before creating the array: `if (!is_empty($value['options']['Colors']) && !is_array($value['options']['Colors'])`.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the problem is in `array_merge`, but i guess if you check before you add the color in database it will be easier to sort. So just replace the `foreach` iteration to insert for that:

```
foreach ($colorArr as $colors) {
    if(trim(chop($colors))!='') $stmt->execute(array(':pid' => $PID, ':colors' => $colors));
}
```

All in all I would change your code to be more clear:

```
$option=$value['options'];
// Check if values are set.
if(!isset($option['Colors'])) $option['Colors']=array();
if(!isset($option['Color'])) $option['Color']=array();

// Convert to array if dont
if(!is_array($option['Colors'])) $option['Colors']=array($option['Colors']);
if(!is_array($option['Color'])) $option['Color']=array($option['Color']);

// Finally merge
$colorArr = array_merge($option['Colors'], $option['Color']);
```

and so on...

Hope it helps!

Comment: Have you put if(trim(chop($colors))!='') before execute?

Comment: I have corrected the issue myself and posted resolution below my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing the lines

```
if(isset($value['options']['Colors'])) {
    $colorArr = $value['options']['Colors'];
}
```

**To**

```
if(isset($value['options']['Colors']) and $value['options']['Colors'] != null and $value['options']['Colors'] !='') {
     $colorArr = $value['options']['Colors'];
}
```